# Can a donation request be added to a death notice?

Tags: death, synagogue, mussar-ethics

When a member or loved one dies, a congregation sends its members a death notice. Without asking the survivors, they add at the end: "Click here to make a donation to the congregation in memory of the deceased".

Is this Jewishly and halachically ethical or is it akin to lawyers chasing ambulances?

(What I believe is unethical is to ASK for a donation right at the time of a death, and while announcing it, as if one were trying to benefit from someone else's demise. Obviously, there is nothing wrong (and plenty right) with a spontaneous and unsolicited donation.)

Comment: sounds like a *chilul hashem*

Comment: @maurice thanks for the edit, +1

Answer (score -3):

1. Tzedoko is a great Mitzvah, so great a Beis Din can force others to donate.
2. After a person passes, we try to maximize the merits of the deceased by doing Mitzvos in their name. Because their property is practically the last thing that connects them to this world, and following the Halacha that the inheritance requires Maaser Ksafim (separating 1/10th) giving a donation in the name of the deceased is not only permitted but very desirable.

We can see it very commonly in Israel when a person passes, suddenly you see new fancy lamps and Parochet and computer screens in the local shul - all from his sons' inheritance's Maaser.